# Python - Indent on a Return Statement

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, export-to-csv

I am slightly revamping an old function i wrote a while back to produce a report. Initially, the generated report was routed to a specified path for the user to go pick up, but i decided to try to give the user the option to also download the report at point of request (*by incorporating send_file*). Hence the code block(s) below.

EXHIBIT A

```
@VVV.route("/reports/users")
def users_report():
    if not session.get("logged_in"):
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        suffix = datetime.now()
        suffix2 = str(suffix)
        suffix3 = suffix2.split(" ")
        suffix4 = suffix.strftime('%H%M%S')
        with open(r'<path>\tahnreports_sysusers_%s_%s.csv' %(suffix3[0],suffix4), 'w', newline='') as start_key:
            #newline parameter avoids the extra line space between rows in the csv.

            csv_header = ("WID", "F_NAME", "L_NAME", "ORG_ROLE", "ORG_STATUS", "SYS_LOGIN_ID")
            csv_out_01 = csv.writer(start_key)
            csv_out_01.writerow(csv_header)
            x15 = divo.session.query(pearl.work_id, pearl.user_fname, pearl.user_lname, pearl.user_category, pearl.user_status,
                                    pearl.login_id)
            for i in x15:
                csv_out_02 = csv.writer(start_key)
                csv_out_02.writerow(i)
            AAA = (r'<path>\tahnreports_sysusers_%s_%s.csv' %(suffix3[0],suffix4))
            return send_file(AAA, as_attachment=True)
```

EXHIBIT B:

```
@VVV.route("/reports/users")
def users_report():
    if not session.get("logged_in"):
        return render_template("login.html")
    else:
        suffix = datetime.now()
        suffix2 = str(suffix)
        suffix3 = suffix2.split(" ")
        suffix4 = suffix.strftime('%H%M%S')
        with open(r'<path>\tahnreports_sysusers_%s_%s.csv' %(suffix3[0],suffix4), 'w', newline='') as start_key:
            #newline parameter avoids the extra line space between rows in the csv.

            csv_header = ("WID", "F_NAME", "L_NAME", "ORG_ROLE", "ORG_STATUS", "SYS_LOGIN_ID")
            csv_out_01 = csv.writer(start_key)
            csv_out_01.writerow(csv_header)
            x15 = divo.session.query(pearl.work_id, pearl.user_fname, pearl.user_lname, pearl.user_category, pearl.user_status,
                                    pearl.login_id)
            for i in x15:
                csv_out_02 = csv.writer(start_key)
                csv_out_02.writerow(i)
            AAA = (r'<path>\tahnreports_sysusers_%s_%s.csv' %(suffix3[0],suffix4))
    return send_file(AAA, as_attachment=True)
```

My issue is trying to understand why these 2 code blocks behave differently. Both functions below are identical except for one small difference - ***the indent on the return statement***. And while they both generate AND also prompt the user to download the report, Exhibit_A sometimes produces an empty file, while Exhibit_B always produces a genuine report. I figure this is tied to the indent of the return statement, but i can't seem to quite put my thumb on it.

To further elaborate on the issue. I generated a report 10 times each, using both functions. Exhibit_A produced 8 out of 10 reports, 2 of which are blank files, while Exhibit_B produces 10 out of 10. Reports from both functions look intact with the exception of the 2 blank files from Exhibit_A. I'd love some feedback on the odd behavior from Exhibit_A.

**ADDENDUM**: Exhibit_B is likely best practice but my thinking is that Exhibit_A should work as well since the "AAA" variable is outside of the 'for-loop sequence', and it does work - but not all the time. Feedback appreciated. Thanks.

[image: exhibit_A]

[image: exhibit_B]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In A, you call `send_file` inside the `with` context, meaning the file is still open for writing, and may not have been flushed to disk (or readable).

In B, you wait until the `with` has ended (and hence the file has been closed) before calling `send_file`.

(edit) FWIW, here's how I'd clean it up for readability -- the extra level of indentation added by the `else` makes the `with` subtlety harder to spot, and all the extra variables don't help either.  It wasn't even obvious to me on first glance that the file you're sending in `send_file` is the same one you were writing because the expression that builds the file path is both overly complex and copy+pasted in two places.  Having a different writer for each row is also confusing -- I don't think it hurts anything, but I don't think it adds any benefit either.

```
@VVV.route("/reports/users")
def users_report():
    if not session.get("logged_in"):
        return render_template("login.html")

    output_path = (
        r'<path>\tahnreports_sysusers_%s.csv'
        % datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
    )
    with open(output_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        csv_out = csv.writer(file)
        csv_out.writerow((
            "WID",
            "F_NAME",
            "L_NAME",
            "ORG_ROLE",
            "ORG_STATUS",
            "SYS_LOGIN_ID"
        ))  # header
        csv_out.writerows(divo.session.query(
            pearl.work_id,
            pearl.user_fname,
            pearl.user_lname,
            pearl.user_category,
            pearl.user_status,
            pearl.login_id
        ))  # data
    return send_file(output_path, as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: So a contextmanager isnt guaranteed to hit `__exit__` on a return?   Unlike `try/finally`?  Oh, I think I get it:  `sendfile` is loading the file *within the context*.

Comment: I think it hits before the `return`, but *not* before the `send_file`!